# Por que ao cortar um array fora do intervalo ele não está devolvendo 'nil'?

Tags: ruby

A documentação ruby fala que ao tentar "cortar" um array usando um índice inválido ele irá devolver nil, então porque eu recebo sempre um array vázio no índice após o último índice válido?

```
array = [0, 1, 2]

# retornando um array vazio como esperado
p array[2,0] # []

# o índice 3 não existe então por que ele retorna '[]'?
p array[3,0] # []

# fora do intervalo retorne 'nil'
p array[4,0] # nil
```

Answer (score 0):

O método que está chamando é este [array[start, length]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D).

A documentação diz:

> If start == self.size and length >= 0, returns a new empty Array.

Ou seja, se `start` for do tamanho do array e `length` for maior ou igual a zero, então, ele retorna um novo array vazio.